# Routing to rails server from local IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, rack-pow

I have a rails app running on standard port 3000.  I can access it from localhost:3000 just fine, but I want to access it from my LAN address as well.  (http://192.168.1.x:3000).  When I try to use the LAN IP in my browser, I get a connection refused error.  I am using POW (http://pow.cx/), which may be the culprit, but cannot sort how.  I CAN access http://192.168.1.x which delivers the default pow landing page, so it seems like the IP resolution is working, but for some reason not on the port my app is serving on.

Comment: I get the same result running on the WebRick server, unless I bind it to my local IP. `rails s -b 192.168.56.1` I'm not sure how you specifiy that in POW though.

Comment: well. that totally works and gets me where I need to be.  I didn't realize it was bound to a specific IP, but I guess that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to help. Yea I guess the default binds to localhost only, aka 127.0.0.1